# $E=\left\{ \frac{n}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $and $F=\left\{ \frac{1}{1-x}:0\leq x<1\right\} $ is open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Question**Which of The following is open or closed $E=\left\{ \frac{n}{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $and
>   F=$\left\{ \frac{1}{1-x}:0\leq x<1\right\} $
>   [image]

**MY Approach**

Let $f$ : $E\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$defined by $f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=n$

I do not know ,It is continuous or not But if yes ,then E is closed

Help me , how to define a continuous function to know that set is
open or closed?

Comment: Since $n\in\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\ldots\}$ then $n\in(0,\infty)$ which is an open interval. And, since any open interval is an open set, then $E$ is an open set and thus the only option to choose is $(c)$ because it is the only option that asserts $E$ is not closed. Now we do have one other option, namely $(d)$, but using this method of logic, we see that $x\in[0,\infty)$ so this is not an open interval; it is half-open. Thus, $F$ is a "clopen" set as they say. So, we strike out this option and the only one left is $(c)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\ldots\}$ is closed set in R

Comment: @user477343 Just give me one counterexample of $n\in\mathbb{N}$$\subset\mathbb{R}$$\nRightarrow$$n\in\mathbb{R}$ and i'll will accept i know nothing

Comment: Sorry. What I was supposed to say was that $\mathbb{N}$ is a closed set in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Not $\mathbb{R}$ I think. Go to the link for more info $\longrightarrow$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, let $\mathbb{N}\in[0,\infty]$. Since this is an *inclusive* range (a closed interval) then this means that $\infty$ is included as an element on this range. But $\infty$ is not a number and can never be truly reached, so it cannot be treated as an element, and so it cannot be included. Thus, $\mathbb{N} = (0, \infty)$, unless we *extend* the real number line (or simply, the set $\mathbb{R}$) which is what the wikipedia article talks about. I guess this is a simpler explanation as opposed to the article, or at least it gives some insight into the detail of it all.

Comment: @Mohan , this is a question from a last year iit jam exam.

Comment: @Abhishek All my question on mse are from iit jam exam,I think you should see them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is not closed since $1$ is an accumulation point of $E$ which does not belong to $E$.

For the set $F$, actually $F=[1,\infty)$, so $F$ is closed.

Comment: how $[1,\infty)$ is closed?

Comment: Since its complement, $(-\infty,1)$, is open.

Comment: @MohanSharma the complement of any set is the empty set $\varnothing$. Therefore, if a set has an open complement, it has to be closed.

Comment: can you give me some reference of similar questions on mse?

Comment: Try the *Schaum's Outline General Topology*, it contains lot of working examples.

Comment: @user284331 , I've Schaum's  outline for general topology 391 solved problems but there are not such type of questions.

Comment: The closest would be Chapter 4 of Schaum's Outline. But you may take a look for William R. Wade, *Introduction to Analysis*, Chapter 8, 9.